# website Caching image gallery

Tags: caching, browser

I have a website that shows hundreds / thousands of images to users. Users reload the gallery fairly frequently, but their caches are invariably not big enough to save the images from visit to visit, and have to slowly re-download.

What are good ways to ensure that images get cached? I've already ruled out using localstorage. What advice can you give me?

Just to be clear, the http headers are set correctly (folks with big caches get instantaneous loads), just that the browser default caches are not big enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered caching on the server-side like [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) in front of your webserver? If you have enough memory on your server(s) this will help alot on the download-time for your users (and your serverload).

Or are you just interested in client-side cache? If so, it would help if you could post your http cache-headers.

Comment: I'm talking about static images, am already using a cdn. The question is just for client side caching.

Comment: Ok. For the record varnish is great for caching static images. But if you already use a CDN (which I assume have some kind of caching) and only interested in client side I don't have any other suggestions than setting the Cache-Control: max-age to a reasonable value.